# List<SomeObject> mList is not supported in Realm

Tags: realm, realm-list

I am working with Realm ORM for my application. My Application has three Model classes that extends RealmObject. In one of the class I have defined a List  of object which is creating problem. 
my first class;

```
      public class Party extends RealmObject implements Parcelable{
            public String name;
            public String name_en;
            public String name_ne;
            public String address;
            public String phoneNumber;

    //get and setters

    //parceable

 }
```

My second class;

```
public class CreatePurchaseOrderRow extends RealmObject implements Parcelable {
    public String name;
    public float amount;
    public String specification;
    public String remarks;
    public Party party;

// getter setter

//parceable

}
```

And finally My third class implements List of objects of Second class. that is,

```
public class CreatePurchasOrder extends RealmObject implements Parcelable {
    public int num;
    public Date date;
    public List<CreatePurchaseOrderRow> createPurchaseOrderRows;

//getter setter

//parceable

}
```

the List feeds is creating problem.

[i have the screenshot for error message here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLscQ.png)

Realm is not schemaless database. I tried finding the solutions but i cannot. Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Use `RealmList` if you want to persist that into the database, otherwise use `@Ignore`.

Comment: I tried doing that too. It requires me to change all my List in java class to RealmList. It simply does not support typecasting.

Comment: Yes. Do it. It's the only option

Comment: Yes, you have to use RealmList in a RealmObject

Answer (score 20):

RealmObjects can not have fields of type `List<>`(`java.util.List`), you have to use `RealmList<>` instead:

```
public class CreatePurchasOrder extends RealmObject implements Parcelable {
    public int num;
    public Date date;
    public RealmList<CreatePurchaseOrderRow> createPurchaseOrderRows;

    //getter setter

    //parceable
}
```

See also: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#many-to-many